# How to write query value inside of query of mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array in mongo document as below.

```
{
  company: [ 
    {name: "exist"}, 
    {name: "cool"},
    {name: "ho"}
  ]
}
```

And I want to get rid of a data in the array with position value.

So I made a query.

```
   await Company.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: "xdef"
      },
      {
        $unset: {
           'company.1': 1
        }
      }
    })
```

It works very well. And now,I want to put position by query.

```
   await Company.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: "xdef"
      },
      {
        $unset: {
           `company.{req.query.position}`: 1
        }
      }
    })
```

But it gives me an error. How can I make a code for this situation adequately? 
Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [computed property names](https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/). And you are missing `$` also in the string literal.

```js
 await Company.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: "xdef"
  }, {
    $unset: {
      [`company.${req.query.position}`]: 1
    }
  }
})
```

> With **Computed Property Names** you can use an expression that will
> be computed as a property name on an object.